# R: pass function with multiple parameters to data frame rows, using only some columns

Tags: r, function, parameters, dataframe, apply

What I am trying to do seems to be super simple, but I just cannot get around it, and I've looked around for similar questions, but still cannot solve it... most likely it's a stupid question, but here it goes...

I have one column that lists positions and 2 other that list start and end, just need to check whether the position is within the range defined by start and end, for each row...

MWE:

```
within.range <- function(pos, start, end){
  if (pos>=start & pos<=end){
    return(TRUE)
  } else{
    return(FALSE)
  }
}

my.df <- data.frame(gene=c("A","B","C","D","E"), chr=c(1,2,3,4,5), pos=as.numeric(c(34,23,6,46,765)), start=as.numeric(c(45,15,2,32,765)), end=as.numeric(c(86,38,9,41,767)))
my.df
```

How can I pass the function to the data frame?? My best attempt is:

```
apply(my.df[,c("pos","start","end")], 1, within.range, start=my.df$start, end=my.df$end)
```

But it is obviously incorrect... Maybe there is a whole better way to accomplish the same... Thanks!

Comment: In your function, you don't need the if statement as you're asking " if TRUE return(TRUE) else retrun(FALSE)" so your function can be "reduced" to only `pos>=start & pos<=end`. Your `apply` statement cannot work because you're entering a vector of length 5 for start and end where each call to your function needs a unnique number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need in `apply` loops here, just do

```
with(my.df, start <= pos & end >= pos)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

If you want to add it as a column, use `transform`

```
transform(my.df, check.pos = start <= pos & end >= pos)
#   gene chr pos start end check.pos
# 1    A   1  34    45  86     FALSE
# 2    B   2  23    15  38      TRUE
# 3    C   3   6     2   9      TRUE
# 4    D   4  46    32  41     FALSE
# 5    E   5 765   765 767      TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can work :

```
check.pos<-apply(my.df[,3:5],1,function(vec){vec[1] >= vec[2] & vec[1] <= vec[3]})


> check.pos
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: this is perfect for what I want to accomplish thanks!!
but for the general question of passing a given function with multiple parameters to a data frame, using some columns only... is there a solution?

Comment: @DaniCee, it depends on your "multiple paremeters", you can do (apply(df[,somecolumns],1,myfunction,param1=param1,param2=param2)` as you did but if the parameters are the same for each "call" of the function

Answer (score 0):

Easy to understand Loop:

> checkBetween = c()
>   for (i in 1 : length(my.df)){
>   checkBetween <- append(checkBetween, within.range(my.df$pos[i], my.df$start[i], >my.df$end[i]))
>   }